# Pass jobParameters spring batch in terminal

Tags: spring, spring-boot, command-line, spring-batch

I'm trying to implement a batch service with Spring Batch. My only problem is to pass a jobParameter dynamically.

I'm trying to start this service with docker, so in my docker-compose.yml I'm running this command:

```
java -Dspring.batch.job.names=uploadToS3Job -jar job-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar date=29-05-2018
```

But my field is always null:

```
@Value("#{jobParameters['date'] ?: ''}")
@StepScope
var date: String = ""
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help

Comment: Did it help to solve your issue?

Comment: Actually, it works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use spring-boot-maven project to create spring executable jar,
Then you can add parameters via `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments`. You can run it like this:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments= --job1parameters.date=29-05-2018

@Value("${job1parameters.date}")
@StepScope
var date: String = ""
```

Comment: How can we pass multiple arguments here?